ssue with Automatic Updates to Outdated Instances in CodeDeploy
I am writing to report an issue we have encountered with AWS CodeDeploy. We have observed that, under certain circumstances, CodeDeploy deploys an outdated revision of our application to Amazon EC2 instances. Specifically, when new EC2 instances are launched into an Auto Scaling group (ASG) while a CodeDeploy deployment is in progress, these instances receive an older revision of our application rather than the latest one.
This issue is causing inconsistencies in our deployment process and impacting the reliability of our application. We would appreciate your assistance in investigating this matter and providing guidance on how to ensure that all instances receive the most recent revision during deployments.
The issue of CodeDeploy deploying an outdated revision to EC2 instances in an Auto Scaling group
We expected that all new EC2 instances launched into the Auto Scaling group during an ongoing CodeDeploy deployment would receive the most recent revision of the application, ensuring consistency across all instances. However, despite our efforts, instances continue to receive older revisions under certain circumstances.

You need to configure automatic updates of outdated instances, this an option of your deplyment group, From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/deployment-groups-configure-advanced-options.html:
aws deploy update-deployment-group arguments --outdated-instances-strategy UPDATE|IGNORE


Hope this solve your issue
